# Is it possible to run Node.js on Windows 8.1?

Tags: node.js, windows-8.1

When I try to install packages in npm I consistently get errors like the following:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.t
argets(64,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform T
oolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, please i
nstall Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the c
urrent Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the sol
ution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...". [C:\Projects\framework
\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_m
odules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]`

I have Visual Studio 12 and Visual Studio Express 10.

I've tried many things, and at this point I'guessing that Windows 8 does not support Node, but if anyone has any luck, let me know.

Have people had reasonable experiences running Node under Cygwin?

Comment: I'm running node 0.10.26 on Windows 8.1. Had no problem installing it. I also have cygwin installed. Maybe you are facing some sort of conflict with Visual Studio. Have you tried to search for this error on Google?

Comment: I don't think this is related with Node.js, but the module your are installing. From the message you have I think you are trying to install `karma`, and its build script was using VS2010.

Comment: @ShaunXu I get the error on many modules when I try to install different things.  It seems to be related to something called node-gyp, which is used to install lots of things.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros I have searched on Google it told me to install a number of things and do a number of things to the classpath, but there is no fix.

But thank you for telling me that you got it to work.

Comment: Hi Joe, yes if the module you are going to with C++ codes then you need to compile. Almost all modules utilizes node-gyp as the build system and many of them rely on VS2010 C++ compiler. If you don't want to manually change the build script to your environment like me, you have to install VS2010 (or at least VS2010 C++ Express).

Comment: @ShaunXu I did install it.  No help.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem on Windows 8, have you tried to install python 2.x? Because node-gyp needs python to generate the configurations to make the compilations later.